# Strange Replacement in Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

Why doesn't this work (in php)?

```
$string=" https://youtu.be/g434EnjOOuU ";

$result=preg_replace("@https?://youtu.be/([a-z0-9-_]*)@isU","[YOUTUBE]$1[/YOUTUBE]",$string);
```

---

```
Result = [YOUTUBE][/YOUTUBE]g434EnjOOuU

Instead of: [YOUTUBE]g434EnjOOuU[/YOUTUBE]
```

I just can't figure out what the replacement comes at the end of the string instead of at the right place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `U` PCRE_UNGREEDY modifier that makes `*` to act as a lazy quantifier. When a lazily quantified pattern appears at the end of the pattern it usually matches an empty string.

See the [fixed regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qrPxxf/1).